# How to get Azure Policy compliance report using PowerShell for a specific Resource and for a specific policy?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-policy

I want to get the Azure Policy Compliance report for a particular resource and for a particular policy. How to achieve this using PowerShell?
e.g. for a Azure VM and for a custom policy "Deny-Firewall".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the Azure Policy Compliance data with PowerShell, please refer to the following script

1. Get data for a particular policy

```
# get the policy compliance status
 Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyDefinitionName <the policy definitionName>

# get the policy evaluation result
Get-AzPolicyEvent -PolicyDefinitionName <the policy definitionName>
```

2.1. Get data for a particular resource

```
# get the policy compliance status
 Get-AzPolicyState -ResourceId <>

# get the policy evaluation result
Get-AzPolicyEvent -ResourceId <>
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data)

Comment: thank you for the commands. Just want to check - for a single resource id how can I get a compliance report for a single policy. the above command Get-AzPolicyState -ResourceId <>will return all the policies for the specified resource. How to get the single policy report for a resource.

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni You can use the command `Get-AzPolicyEvent -ResourceId <>  -Filter "PolicyDefinitionName eq '<>'"`.

Comment: does the filter works for custom policy as well like "Deny-Firewall"?

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni Yes you also can do that.